# How do I measure the area of a segment in customized wheels and tools?

Tags: area, surfaces

**Background**

I'm employed by a coating company. Our speciality is epoxy coating.

It's difficult for me to measure the area to be painted or coated. Most of our work involves custom wheels or tools. The customer provides us with a diagram of the wheel or job and asks us to quote on that particular area of epoxy coating.

I have attached a sample image below. We need to find the areas highlighted in bold in the image (pulley wheel teeth).

[image]

I would be grateful if anyone could help with a step by step method or formula to help me resolve this issue, as it is currently difficult to compute anything precise.

*Note: we are only provided with a jpeg file and so 3D modelling / using CAD files is unfortunately not an option (as mentioned in the comments).*

Comment: CAD 3D model...

Comment: We get the file as a jpeg, not pdf or any formats that work with cad. So we need to do it mathematically.

Comment: I suppose that drawing shows body of rotation with horizontal axis of rotation. Is it correct? Do you need to find surface area of surface shown by bold line?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu yes, you are correct, I need to find the area shown in bold line.